# How does Spring Boot publish Authentication*Event?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to better understand how Spring Boot publishes `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`s and `AuthenticationFailure*Event`s in order to implement a similar behavior in my own application. Therefore I would be very grateful for any information and articles on this.

At the moment, although I have implemented a `DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher`, no events seem to be published. Maybe someone here has a tip for me too. I use a custom `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` and a custom `Providermanager`.
`AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and `AuthenticationFailureHandler` are set on the
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

This setup alone does not seem to be sufficient for Spring Boot to publish successful and unsuccessful login attempts as events. Where in this chain do I have to intervene and how in order to be able to work with listeners?

**Many thanks for any help**

**Edit:**
Maybe useful: the current Spring Boot version is 3.x (Spring Framwork and Security are 6.x).

**Edit 2:**
Spring Boot Startup Log:

```java
13:02:10 INFO  - [kground-preinit] o.h.v.i.u.Version                                 :  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.0.Final
13:02:10 INFO  - [           main] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                                :  SisterMaryStigmataPool - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:example-db user=SA
13:02:10 INFO  - [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                            :  SisterMaryStigmataPool - Start completed.

13:02:10 INFO  - [           main] a.p.t.h.Application                               :  Starting Application using Java 17 with PID 7604 (XXX)
13:02:10 DEBUG - [           main] a.p.t.h.Application                               :  Running with Spring Boot v3.0.2, Spring v6.0.4
13:02:10 INFO  - [           main] a.p.t.h.Application                               :  The following 1 profile is active: "development"
13:02:11 INFO  - [           main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate         :  Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
13:02:11 INFO  - [           main] o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate         :  Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 110 ms. Found 9 JPA repository interfaces.
13:02:11 WARN  - [           main] o.s.c.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer   :  Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.SpringHttpSessionConfiguration
13:02:11 INFO  - [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer                       :  Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8087 (https) 8086 (http)
13:02:11 INFO  - [           main] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                         :  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8087"]
13:02:11 INFO  - [           main] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                         :  Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8086"]
13:02:11 INFO  - [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardService                           :  Starting service [Tomcat]
13:02:11 INFO  - [           main] o.a.c.c.StandardEngine                            :  Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]                                 :  Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext    :  Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1399 ms
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                            :  LeelooDallasMultipassPool - Starting...
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] c.z.h.p.HikariPool                                :  LeelooDallasMultipassPool - Added connection conn10: url=jdbc:h2:example-db user=SA
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] c.z.h.HikariDataSource                            :  LeelooDallasMultipassPool - Start completed.
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] o.s.b.a.h.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration              :  H2 console available at '/admin/h2'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:example-db'
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper                               :  HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] o.h.Version                                       :  HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
13:02:12 WARN  - [           main] o.h.o.deprecation                                 :  HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
13:02:12 INFO  - [           main] SQL dialect                                       :  HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
13:02:13 INFO  - [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator                :  HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
13:02:13 INFO  - [           main] o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean    :  Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
13:02:14 WARN  - [           main] s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration:  spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
13:02:14 DEBUG - [           main] h.s.i.InternalUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:  Filter 'internalUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' configured for use

13:02:14 TRACE - [           main] tion$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer:  Eagerly initializing {webSecurityConfig=com.example.configuration.security.WebSecurityConfig@3b07b706}
13:02:14 DEBUG - [           main] DefaultPasswordEncoderAuthenticationManagerBuilder:  No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
13:02:14 INFO  - [           main] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain                :  Will secure Or [Ant [pattern='/admin/h2/**']] with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@5c085d4a, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3fc0a2c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@34692767, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@59f4df4e, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@ce4a8a2, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@24bd88df, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@78d816e6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@562fa8f2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1f41742f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@64176780]
13:02:14 INFO  - [           main] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain                :  Will secure Or [Mvc [pattern='/favicon.ico'], Mvc [pattern='/css/**'], Mvc [pattern='/scripts/**'], Mvc [pattern='/img/**'], Mvc [pattern='/webjars/**']] with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4bb5ba10, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@67d44ae9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@30f454f4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@11f4d2b8, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@615c9e9b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@7ce3c0cc, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1f5faa89, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@519fa526]
13:02:14 INFO  - [           main] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain                :  Will secure Or [Mvc [pattern='/api/**']] with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@27868127, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@4a2f4bfa, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@5172cce4, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2461a62c, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3044dd80, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@60d1b2a7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@47ccb397, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@efac87a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@17f83573, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@371fcc18, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@1ac24c17]
13:02:15 INFO  - [           main] o.s.s.w.DefaultSecurityFilterChain                :  Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@10b40e87, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@1290fc6a, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@19181b06, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6d4f29a4, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@758f755a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3fd7be2d, com.example.security.internal.InternalUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@28261231, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@173398da, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@72584c3f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6ee7c941, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@18c805b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@4a09f5b]
13:02:15 WARN  - [           main] o.s.s.c.a.w.b.WebSecurity                         :  

********************************************************************
**********        Security debugging is enabled.       *************
**********    This may include sensitive information.  *************
**********      Do not use in a production system!     *************
********************************************************************

13:02:15 INFO  - [           main] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                         :  Starting ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8087"]
13:02:15 INFO  - [           main] o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol                         :  Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8086"]
13:02:15 INFO  - [           main] o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer                       :  Tomcat started on port(s): 8087 (https) 8086 (http) with context path ''
13:02:15 INFO  - [           main] a.p.t.h.Application                               :  Started Application in 5.97 seconds (process running for 7.301)
```

Comment: Are you using spring-boot-starter-security? The authentication works fine? Only events not fired? Can you post the startup logs, please.

Comment: Hello Mar-Z. Thanks for taking a look. Yes, i am using spring-boot-starter-security. I have set all logging with Log4j, should i pick something explicit for you, or log a special class on trace? I have at least pasted the current Spring Boot starting logs above.

Comment: Now I read carefully your question and I think I get it. You have configured Authentication Handlers in your custom code. In this case the events will not be fired. You should just use the methods of the handlers, like onAuthenticationFailure.

Comment: I have deactivated the two authentication handlers as a test, but this hasn't changed anything. I therefore rather think that the fact that I use a custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter somehow results in no events being published - or am I completely wrong? Is there anywhere I can read about how this works in an unmodified application?

Answer (score 0):

To listen for authentication events, you must first publish an AuthenticationEventPublisher. Spring Security’s DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher works fine for this purpose:

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationEventPublisher authenticationEventPublisher
    (ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    return new DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
}
```

Then you can use Spring’s @EventListener support:

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationEvents {
    @EventListener
    public void onSuccess(AuthenticationSuccessEvent success) {
        // ...
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onFailure(AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent failures) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I've done. But unfortunately, within a custom log in setup Spring Boot seems to abstain from publishing events itself. So my question is, where do I have to modify what, to get these events published? Do I have to publish them by myself? And if, can I read somewhere in a Spring documentation how Spring does it, so I can adopt it?